# Rails flash messages not clearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my environment: Rails 3.2.0 and Ruby 1.9.2.

After upgrading my session storage to database, none of my flash messages are clearing after any requests.  If I revert back to cookie session storage, flash messages are clearing as expected.  Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks!

Paul

Comment: I am using redirect_to.  I know what the problem is now.  I mentioned it in the answer below in case anyone encounters this problem :(  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I know what the problem is.  I am using datamapper (dm-rails 1.2) as my persistence layer and there is an issue open for it: github.com/datamapper/dm-rails/issues/30.  I followed the fix as specified in the first post and it solved my problem.

This problem is also mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512253/rails-3-2-datamapper-session-store-flash-object-persisting?rq=1